# Access the property from Typescript union datatype

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a below structure

```
export interface VendorState extends PaginationViewModel {
  vendors: CategoryVendorCommand[] | CategoryVendorCommand;
}
```

model

```
export interface CategoryVendorCommand {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
}
```

Trying to access the property

```
 this.patchValue({ name: item.vendors.name, description: item.vendors.description })
```

Getting an exception as `Property 'name' and 'description' does not exist on type 'CategoryVendorCommand | CategoryVendorCommand[]'`

Comment: One way is this: `(item.vendors as CategoryVendorCommand).name`. But not sure how the code flow going.

Comment: @Mr_Green No I don't need the array part . I am already putting an if condition Array.isArray()

Comment: I didn't understand the requirement then. Did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
const _this = this;
const setPatchValue = (vendor: CategoryVendorCommand) => {
    _this.patchValue({ name: vendor.name, description: vendor.description });
});

// Something like this (untested)

if(Array.isArray(item.vendors)){
    item.vendors.forEach((vendor) => setPatchValue(vendor));
}
else {
    setPatchValue(item.vendors);
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but having an exeception at line const setPatchValue = (vendor) => {
    this.patchValue({ name: vendor.name, description: vendor.description });
});

Comment: @SanJaisy What is the exception? I am assuming some things and will do changes to code till then

Comment: A class member cannot have the const keyword

Comment: You have to keep the above whole code inside a single method.